# Pressure sensitive tablet input in Javafx?

Tags: javafx, tablet

I'd like to write a pen-stroke drawing app using JavaFX.  I have a pressure sensitive drawing tablet and it would be really nice to be able to read the pressure and tilt values of the pen.  JavaFX has an API that handles mouse, touch and swipe inputs, but there doesn't seem to be anything that yields pressure values.

I've used JPen before, but it seems to be for Swing.  Is there a JavaFX equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

There is a related question on the forum site of JPen.

http://sourceforge.net/p/jpen/discussion/753961/thread/d6028fb2/

Maybe the answers can give you a hint of how to extend JPen to work with JavaFX. Their architecture does not seem to depend on AWT.

Your own question there concerning JavaFX has not been answered so far. Maybe you can push it a bit :-)

Answer (score 0):

As discussed JPen does not depend on AWT architecture, so you can adapt JPen to JavaFX.

[Here is code](https://gist.github.com/itsu-dev/fe586cc4df9abd601abff6b7b49415b1)

Comment: Hi Itsu, could you provide some short code snippets here and expand on your answer a little please?